# C++ algorithm for prime numbers in range

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to implement my program to check if a number is a prime number by checking if it is not divisible by any of the prime numbers before it. As a sample prime number, it is given the input of 2 when **primes.size()=0**. However, my program prints all the numbers from 2-100 instead.

```
bool IsPrime(int number){
        vector <int> primes;
        if(primes.size()==0){
            primes.push_back(number);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i<=primes.size()-1; ++i){
                if(number % primes[i]==0){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        primes.push_back(number);
        return true;
    }

    int main(){
        for(int i = 2; i<=100; ++i){
            if(IsPrime(i)==true){
                cout << i << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `primes` is not `static` so you get a new __empty__ vector each time you run the function. You need to change `vector<int> primes;` to `static vector<int> primes;`

Comment: `primes` is always empty when you check its size.

Comment: variable `primes` vector reset every time call `IsPrime()`. if make `primes` as static (`static vector<int> primes`) or global variable, you can get right answer.

Comment: You might find it illuminating to step through your `IsPrime` function to see which `return` statement it is hitting. Do a little debugging so you can ask a more focused question.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the variable *primes* is new every time you call the method **IsPrime()**.
As soon as it finishes a return statement it gets deleted

This means that every time you call **IsPrime()** the variable *primes* will have nothing in it. When you get to the first If statement its size will always be zero which means it will always return true.

Comment: As a side note he can add static to that variable or pass in the variable or make this a class method. Any method to add persistence is fine.